# Bean validation does not work for simpleSelectOneMenu in ICEFaces

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I use jsf 2.1.21, ICEFaces 3.3, Tomcat 7 and hibernate validator 5.1. Component `ace:simpleSelectOneMenu` refers to backing bean field which has `@Min` validation configured. And no bean validation is performed.

```
<ace:simpleSelectOneMenu id="category" value="#{myBean.catId}" label="Category"
                         validatorMessage="Please select category">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="Please select"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Category 1"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Category 2"/>      
</ace:simpleSelectOneMenu>
<h:message id="categoryMsg" for="category"/>

@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {

  @Min(0)
  private int catId;

  public int getCatId() {
     return catId;
  }

  public void setCatId(int catId) {
     this.catId = catId;
  }
}
```

If use `h:selectOneMenu` instead of `ace:simpleSelectOneMenu` then bean validation works. Even more I see that `ace` `SelectOneMenu`  component has validator `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator` added to its validators. But it is not triggered.

I wonder how to make that validator work?
If use other `ace` components like `ace:textEntry` then bean validation works.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible solution could be used `valueChangeListener` of `ace:simpleSelectOneMenu`.

It is called in `validate phase`. And for component is created validator `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator` by jsf. So `valueChangeListener` just may pass through all validators of the component and trigger ones of `BeanValidator` type. Catching `ValidatorException` and calling `FacesContext.validationFailed()` simulates validation failure and no `update model phase` will be called.

```
<ace:simpleSelectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{myBean.validateBean}">

@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
    ...
    public void validateBean(ValueChangeEvent ve) {
        UIInput input = (UIInput) ve.getComponent();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Validator[] validators = input.getValidators();

        for (Validator validator : validators) {
            if (validator instanceof BeanValidator) {
                try {
                    validator.validate(context, input, ve.getNewValue());
                }
                catch (ValidatorException e) {
                    input.setValid(false);
                    String txt = input.getValidatorMessage();
                    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,  txt, txt);
                    context.addMessage(input.getClientId(), message);
                    context.validationFailed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great workaround. Validation message can be retrieved directly from exception.